# QuickBooksOnline authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, quickbooks-online

I had implemented (C#, ASP.NET MVC) QBO authentication with button (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/widgets#SIWQB) and it works

But i don't want to use this button. I tried to pass QBO authentication without button from documentation, and i'm getting access token (that means that authentication passed successeful imho), but when i'm trying to use access token i get an error:

> message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200;
>   statusCode=401

Is it possible to pass authentication without QB button? Does anyone have example of such auth?

Answer (score 0):

Re - Is it possible to pass authentication without QB button?

Yes, it is possible.

- Using IPP's .net devkit -

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

- Using Dev-defined lib -

https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/0913b4c224de758fde0a

Thanks

Comment: Your answer suggest that end-user has authorized app. I have no AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret! I want to authorize application - that mean i want to get AccessToken and AccessSecret

Comment: You need to create an app in appcenter to get consumerKey and consumerSecret. You can use that to generate accessToken and accessSecret corresponding to the target relam. 
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. But i want to do it programmatically. I have a lot of users and i can't to process each credentials manually. Share consumer keys and apptoken - is not secure. Looks like there is no way to acheive that, except QBO button, well, i'll use button.

Comment: You can implement connect to QB wizard using which you app's end user can generate accessToken and accessSecret. You should persist those token in your app's db for reuse. 
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/widgets
Thanks